# Braintree javascript script not working on UserAgent ios10

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, braintree

I added the following blade code in my view file for adding of credit cards via Braintree.

```
<form id="form-add-card" class="popup-form" method="POST" action="{{ url('account/credit-card') }}">
    <div id="card-braintree">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12 mbm">
                <h6>Add a card</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" id="card_no"  maxlength="16" type="text" data-braintree-name="number" class="validate">
                <label for="card_no">Card Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="MM / YY" id="valid_until" type="text" data-braintree-name="expiration_date" class="validate">
                <label for="valid_until">Valid Until</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12">
                <p class="small-notice light-text mtm">We accept both Visa and MasterCard payment and has a validated certification for PCI DSS Compliant Service Provider.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn load">Save Card</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and then set up the javascript for Braintree as follows:

```
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        braintree.setup('{{ $client_token }}', 'custom', { id:'form-add-card',
            onPaymentMethodReceived: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

If I try to add a credit card via web through this form, I would have the payment method nonce and credit card details returned. However, if I were to use safari, adding of credit card is not possible, it will pass in an empty payment method nonce into my form. This occurs in chrome ios and safari. Android chrome and web chrome is working fine.

Thoughts?

Edit:
I'm still having the same issue in Safari/ios devices despite updating the braintree script.
[image: In my safari console, this is presented]

Comment: The "hot-linked" version of Braintree's library is deprecated. Can you update your code to the latest version of braintree, `https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.32.1.min.js`, and see if that does the trick? If you are still seeing this issue after updating your script source, please be more specific with the issue you are seeing (screenshots, any console error messages, browser versions) to help us troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: I am still seeing the same issue with the updated script file. Do I have to change data-braintree-name to hosted field in order to make it work? Basically, the payment_method_nonce hidden field is added but when I send the form over, it would not occupy the field. It will send over an empty payment_method_nonce param.

Answer (score 0):

Shall place this here in case someone has the same issue,

I logged my server and noticed that the form is submitted twice, the first time without payment_method_nonce parameter value, and the second is with. Somehow in Safari and ios devices, the form only submit once with the empty value, therefore not allowing the adding of the card via braintree. To fix this, instead of:

```
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn load">Save Card</button>
        </div>
```

I replaced it with:

```
        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input class="waves-effect waves-light btn load" type="submit" id="submit" value="Save Card">
        </div>
```

and it works.